# create reply with HeroCard or any type of card inside PromptOptions

Tags: c#, botframework

Is there a way to customize the layout of my choices inside the promptoptions?
I want to convert it to card. HeroCard or SuggestedCard. Are there any ways?
The default layout is always carousel.

Also, if i put space on my text it changes the form.
1st image is without spaces, 2nd is with spaces. see the difference.
[image]
[image]
Thanks!

```
var options = new PromptOptions()
{
Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please choose a location."),
RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Sorry, please choose a location from the list."),
Choices = ChoiceFactory.ToChoices(new List<string> { "Redmond", "Bellevue", "Seattle" }),
};
return await stepContext.PromptAsync("second", options, cancellationToken);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new reply, add a HeroCard attachment to it with your suggested actions, and add the reply to your prompt options as the prompt attribute. See the code snippet below.

```
private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> PromptForLocation(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Activity reply = stepContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply();

        var heroCard = new HeroCard
    {
        Title = "Please choose a location.",
        Buttons = new List<CardAction> { new CardAction(ActionTypes.PostBack, "Redmond", value: "Redmond"), 
                                            new CardAction(ActionTypes.PostBack, "Bellevue", value: "Bellevue"), 
                                            new CardAction(ActionTypes.PostBack, "Seattle", value: "Seattle") },
    };

    reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>() { heroCard.ToAttachment() };

    var options = new PromptOptions()
        {
        Prompt = reply,
        RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Sorry, please choose a location from the list.")
        };

    return await stepContext.PromptAsync("name", options, cancellationToken);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: hi @tdurnford, I already tried this one, but when ever I select on the choices, it keeps on returning the retry prompt. it never goes on to the next step.

Comment: What kind of prompt are you using?

Comment: ChoicePrompt. should I use other prompt?

Comment: I would recommend using a TextPrompt with a custom validator. If you want to use a choice prompt, you have to either include the Choices property in the prompt options or use a custom validator.